# When i have this command, i can't use any command

Tags: c#, string, list, discord, discord.net

I made this command and i want to be a Universal one, but if i have this command, i get "Unknown command." for all commands, how i can solve that?

My module is public.

Can i change "List< string>" to "string" and in code to convert in "List< string>"?
And if yes, how i can do that?

```
        [Command("addOnList")]
    [Summary("Add a string to a list")]
    public async Task manageList(List<string> list = null, [Remainder]string name = null)
    {
    //Code here
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you can passing the list as "a,b,c"..

```
[Command("addOnList")]
[Summary("Add a string to a list")]
public async Task manageList(string csvList = null, [Remainder]string name = null)
{
    var list = csvList.Split(',').ToList();
    //Code here
}
```